# POST通信をした時にPHP側で値が空になる

Tags: swift, ios, php, json

現在以下のようにパラメーターと共にPOST通信を行なっています。

```
        let parameters: [String:Any] = [
            "Diary": [
                "ID": diary.id,
                "Title": diary.title,
                "Content": diary.content,
                "XTime": diary.xtime,
                "IsShared": diary.isShare
            ]]

        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval = 10
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
```

そしてPHP側は以下のようになっています。

```
  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $data = json_decode($json, true);
  var_dump($json);
```

しかし実際にブラウザには以下のように表示されてしまっています。

string(0) ""

なぜPHP側で値が受け取れていないのでしょうか。
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/107395

Comment: マルチポストって何がいけないんですか？

Comment: 参考になさってください。
 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせてもらいます。

Comment: @tarofess すでに他のサイトで解決したのであればこちらでもその報告をお願いします。解決済みであることを書かないと、未解決の質問だと思って回答しようとした人の時間を無駄にしてしまいます。

Comment: @小川航佑 すみません、解決できているので自己解決したことを記載します。

Comment: @tarofess  ありがとうございます。解決して良かったです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift のコードに

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

を追加するとどうでしょうか？

また、アクセスする url を `https://httpbin.org/post` に変えてみるとどうでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。そちらのコードを追加してもブラウザには値が表示されなかったのですが、返ってきた値をswift側で確認すると、値が入っていました。ブラウザ上に表示される値と返ってきた値が違っていたようでした。